# What language is this on booknooklearning.com?

Tags: programming-languages

On www.booknooklearning.com I saw this code displayed in the header section below the main nav, and which I don't recognize. Can you help me identify the language?

I did a quick search but nothing came up at all. I mean nothing.

[stack_hero layout=”fullscreen” image=”611″ opacity=”5″ height=”30″]

See BookNook in Action with a Live Demo

[/stack_hero]

I'd like to find out what language this is?

Comment: i'd just assume it is css without the < >tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After research the website turns to be Wordpress, witch means PHP. 
The tags stack_hero are Shortcodes that a wordpress theme is using to call theme partials. 
Hope this helps you.